# Difference between superset and universal set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, function-and-relation-composition

1-
Let A={a,b} and B={a,b,c,d,e}.
I know that B is superset of A. But it seems a universal set as well.

2-
If A={a,b}, B= {a,b,c,d,e} and C= {c,d}. B is still a superset of A and C. Is it also a universal set of A and C or is it necessary that Universal set for A and C be
B or U= {a,b,c,d}.

Comment: The universal set is a set of all the elements available i.e. the entire universe of everything.  The thing is, unless we are told what the universe set is we really have no way of knowing what it is.  In this case we are told set $A$ has $a,b$ and set $B$ has $a,b,c,d,e$.  So if we list all the elements we know we can have the are $a,b,c,d,e$.  But is that all in the entire universe? Is there an element $f$ and it just hasn't been used yet?  There's no way we can tell.  We don't know what the universal set is. But we do know it contains at $a,b,c,d,e$ and possibly more elements.

Comment: "Is it also a universal set of A and C " There's no such thing a universal set for some sets but not for others.  There is only *one* universal set and it contains *EVERYTHING* you are ever allowed to use.  It is, in essence, the entire universe (in the context of the problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mistakenly thinking there is some kind of rule or definition to make *the* superset of a set or group of sets, and that you can have a universal set of some sets and another universal set of other sets.

That's not what these mean.

*A* superset of a set means nothing more than a set that contains all the elements.  So for example if $A = \{a,b\}$ then $M = \{a,b,c\}$ is a superset.  And so is $N=\{a,b,f,q\}$ as is $J = \{a,b,w, \phi, \text{Babar the elephant}, apple\}$.  There is no *one* superset.

Now if $A = \{a,b\}$ and $C= \{b,c\}$ then $\{a,b,f,w\}$ is a superset of $A$ but not of $C$.  And $\{b,c, e, m\}$ is a superset of $C$ but not of $A$.  But $\{a,b,c, k, z\}$ is a superset of both.

Now, it's worth noting that $A \cup C$ is the set that contains all the elements of both $A$ and $C$ (and no other elements) so $A\cup C = \{a,b,c\}$.  It may be worth noting that that would mean $A\cup C$ is the smallest possible superset of both $A$ and $C$.  But it not the *only* superset of both $A\cup C$.... (assuming there are more things in your universe than just $a,b,c$.)

....

So what is the universal set?  Well, for every problem there is exactly one universal set and it is the set that has *EVERYTHING* you are allowed to use.

You'll notice in an example above I put some silly things in my set $J$.  I put in $\phi$ (are we allowed to use greek letters?) and I put in Babar the elephant (are we allowed to use fictional children's book characters) and I put in $apple$ (are we allowed to use fruit?)

Are they allowed?  I don't know.  It depends on how the problem was set up and what we are allowed to use.

And that is *all* that the universal set is.  It is the set of everything we are allowed to use.  And there is only *one* for every problem.

So in the problems you mention I see you use the elements $a,b,c,d,e$.  So the universal set must include those (otherwise we couldn't use them).  But what else does it include?

I don't know.  You didn't tell me.  If $a,b,c,d,e$ is everything we are allowed to use then the universal set is $U=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$.  But if we are allowed to use $f$ (even if we *don't* use it) the $f$ must be in the universal set.

Often the Universal set isn't specifically spelled out and it is only implied.  Maybe it is assumed you are taking sets of real numbers and it is assumed the universal set is $\mathbb R$.

EDIT:  The author is defining the universal set to be A set that takes all elements mentioned into account.  As in both example 1 and 2, the only elements mentioned are $a,b,c,d,e$ the universal set is $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ which happens to by set $B$.

In example 1) $B$ is *a* superset of $A$.  The other possible supersets are $\{a,b\}$ (Every set is a superset of itself), $\{a,b,c\},\{a,b,d\},\{a,b,e\},\{a,b,c,d\},\{a,b,c,e\},\{a,b,d,e\}$ and $\{a,b,c,d,e,\}$ (the universal set is *always* a superset of *every* set)

In example 2) $B$ is still a superset of $A$ both and of $C$.  It is the universal set so it is a superset of every set. It is not the universal set of $A$ and $C$.  There is no such thing as *a* universal set for individual sets.  There is only *ONE* universal set for *EVERYTHING*. ANd that is still $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$.  It's true that neither $A$ nor $C$ has element $e$ but $B$ does.  The one universal set for everything must be a superset of *all* sets; not just the two you are talking about.

$A\cup C = \{a,b,c,d\}$ is the *smallest* set that is a superset of *both* $A$ and of $C$.  But the universal set, by definition, would be the *biggest* superset of bot $A$ and of $B$.

Comment: I was talking about universal set in above contexts. I was reading a book and I found,according to the book, that superset of all sets in the given context is called universal set. So I think in above context, in 1- B is superset of A as well as the universal set , 2- again B is superset of A and C and as well as the universal set.

Comment: In that case the Universal set, being the the set of all relevant things being mentioned is $B$ is the universal set as it has everything mentioned.  BTW.... The universal set is *ALWAYS* a superset of every set.

Comment: I have edited my answer in light of the definitions in your text.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of universal set is the set containing all objects or elements and of which all other sets are subsets.

Question 1) If we look at $B = \{a,b,c,d,e \}$, we could say the $B \subseteq U$ if the whole universe of elements are $U = \{ a,b,c,d,e \}$. So if $a,b,c,d,e$ are all the elements in this universe then, yes, $B$ is a equal to the universal set.

Question 2) Let's think of what it means to be a superset. A superset is a set of elements containing all of the elements of another set. So we see that $B$ is a superset of $A$ and $C$ because $B$ has all the elements inside of $A$ and $C$. Thus, $B \supset A$ and $B \supset C$, and if $B$ has all the elements in the universe, then $B$ is equal to the universal set, meaning $B \subseteq U$.

EDIT:

When saying $U = \{a,b,c,d \}$ do you mean for $B = \{ a,b,c,d \}$? No set can have more elements than the universal set.